# Postgres grant readonly role access to database

Tags: postgresql

This has been asked before, but my issue seems unique. Hoping I overlooked something on
PostgreSQL 15.2

I am creating a database as user `appowner` and trying to grant select access to a user `adminuser` by creating the `editor` role.

When doing as `adminuser`, I get:

```
select * from roles;
ERROR:  permission denied for table roles
```

What is the missing permissions that allows select for a ROLE that is granted to a user?

###### To reproduce, start up postgres

```
docker run \
    --name myPostgresDb \
    -p 5455:5432 \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=mysuperuser \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=postgresDB \
    -d \
    postgres
```

###### Run the following as superuser (postgresUser):

```
CREATE USER appowner WITH PASSWORD 'changeme' CREATEDB;
```

###### Connect as appowner

```
create database testdb;
\c testdb
CREATE TABLE testtable(
   role_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   role_name VARCHAR (255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO testtable (role_id, role_name) values (1, 1);
```

###### Run the following as superuser

```
\c testdb
CREATE USER adminuser WITH PASSWORD 'changeme' CREATEDB;
create role editor;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO editor;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO editor;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO editor;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO editor;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO editor;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE testtable TO editor;

grant adminuser to editor;
```

###### Run the following as adminuser (a member of editor)

```
    testdb=> select * from testtable;
    ERROR:  permission denied for table testtable
```

Comment: Alternatively I tried: CREATE ROLE editor INHERIT; ALTER USER adminuser WITH inherit; This issue isn't related to permission inheritance.

Comment: Should your last line as `superuser` not be `grant editor to adminuser`?

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes!!! This is where it went wrong. Thank you!!

Comment: Please do not put the solution into the question. Add an answer and accept that answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLUTION (SOLVED)

This fixed it:

```
grant editor to adminuser;
```

Syntax is:

```
GRANT <role with permissions> 
   TO
 <user or role needing permission>
```